# Solving for $\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{x - 2}{x + 2}$

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

As the question says, I was wondering how you'd go about solving the equation

\begin{align*} 
\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{x - 2}{x + 2}
\end{align*}

for $x$. I've tried various methods and I'm feeling kind of dumb, cause I'm not sure where I'm messing up and I'm sure it's something obvious!

For starters, I set up a triangle like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sODTm.png

since $\cos(x) = \frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$. Then I solved for the missing angle and tried using Law of Sines, but that just resulted in me getting

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x + 2} = \frac{1}{x + 2}
\end{align*}

which was a major facepalm moment for me, because of course. Then I tried setting

\begin{align*}
-1 \le \frac{n-2}{n+2} \le 1
\end{align*}

since $cos(x)$ is between -1 and 1. That resulted in me getting two answers,

\begin{align*}
0 \le x, 0 \le 4 
\end{align*}

Then I tried to solve

\begin{align*}
0 \le \frac{\pi}{x} \le \pi
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\pi \le \frac{\pi}{x} \le 2\pi
\end{align*}

using the same logic as the above. Then, I tried just using algebra:

\begin{align*}
\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) = \frac{x - 2}{x + 2} \\
(x + 2)\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) = (x - 2) \\
x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) + 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) = (x - 2) \\
x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - x = -2 - 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) \\
x ( \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - 1) = -2(1 - \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}))\\
-\frac{x}{2} = \frac {1 - \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) }{ \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - 1 }\\
-\frac{x}{2} = \frac {-\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) + 1 }{ \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - 1 }\\
-\frac{x}{2} = \frac {(-1)(\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - 1) }{ \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) - 1 }\\
-\frac{x}{2} = -1\\
-x = -2\\
x = 2
\end{align*}

But that solution, I realized, was identifiable by inspection (I facepalmed again).

Looking at the graph on Desmos, I saw a bunch of solutions (including the inspection solution of $x = 2$).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAZUS.png

How would I find out those solutions? I can't think of any way to do it and I'm feeling a bit silly, haha. Any help would be appreciated! Apologies about the images, I don't have enough reputation to post them!

Comment: Because $x$ is both inside and outside of the trig function, the equation is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). Except for special cases (such as the by-inspection solution of $x=2$), solutions can only be approximated by numerical methods or expressed in terms of special functions such as [Lambert's W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @Blue Thanks so much! I'm still going through math so I didn't actually know. If I wanted to approximate this function, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: @ekoral: One of the easiest methods of approximating is to do what you did: Graph the relation in, say, Desmos and *look* at the decimal approximations of the roots. Computational techniques include the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) and [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), the latter of which requires some elementary Calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let $x=\frac 1 y$, you need to *approximate* the zeros of function
$$f(y)=\cos(\pi y)+\frac{2y- 1 }{2y+ 1 }$$ for which
$$f'(y)=-\pi  \sin (\pi  y)+\frac{4}{(2 y+1)^2}$$ You see that $f'(y)$ will cancel closer and closer to integer values of $y$; then the roots will be between two consecutive integers.

Using **one** single iteration of Householder method with $y_0=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$,
the approximation for the $n^{\text{th}}$ root is
$$y_{(n)}=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\Delta_n$$ $$\Delta_n=\frac{\Big[6 n \left(\pi ^2 (n+1)^3+1\right) \Big]-(-1)^n\Big[12 \pi  n (n+1) \Big]} {-\Big[6 \left(3 \pi ^2 (n+1)^2+1\right) \Big]+(-1)^n\Big[\pi ^3 (5 n^2+12n+6) (n+1)^2+6 \pi  (2 n+3) \Big] }$$  This does not count for the trivial $y=0$.

A few numbers

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 0.50000 &  0.50000 \\
 1 & 1.34846 &  1.34823 \\
 2 & 2.73907 &  2.74312 \\
 3 & 3.24360 &  3.23835 \\
 4 & 4.78986 &  4.80128 \\
 5 & 5.20381 &  5.19157 \\
 6 & 6.81370 &  6.83180 \\
 7 & 7.18308 &  7.16442 \\
 8 & 8.82768 &  8.85145 \\
 9 & 9.17039 &  9.14622 \\
 10 & 10.8369 &  10.8655 \\
 20 & 20.8575 &  20.9023 \\
 30 & 30.8652 &  30.9195 \\
 40 & 40.8692 &  40.9299 \\
 50 & 50.8717 &  50.9371 \\
 60 & 60.8733 &  60.9425 \\
 70 & 70.8745 &  70.9467 \\
 80 & 80.8754 &  80.9501 \\
 90 & 90.8762 &  90.9529 \\
 100 & 100.877 &  100.955
\end{array}
\right)$$

This is not fantastic but it could be improved using a few more terms.

For sure, with these estimates, a few iterations of Newton method will polish the solution to the desired accuracy. For example, for $n=100$, they will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & y_k \\
 0 & 100.877 \\
 1 & 100.931 \\
 2 & 100.951 \\
 3 & 100.955
\end{array}
\right)$$